# Best practices for Ruby on Rails service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing some mobile otp validation service and below is my service class

```
require 'nexmo'
class NexmoServices
    def initialize api_key = nil, api_secret = nil, opts = {}
      api_key      = api_key || Rails.application.secrets.nexmo_api_key 
      api_secret   = api_secret || Rails.application.secrets.nexmo_secret_key 

      @nexmo_client = Nexmo::Client.new(
        api_key: api_key, 
        api_secret: api_secret,
        code_length: 6
        )
      @brand = 'CryptoShop'
    end


    def send_verification_code opts 
        @nexmo_client.verify.request(number: opts[:number], brand: @brand)
    end

    def check_verification_code opts
        @nexmo_client.verify.check(request_id: opts[:request_id], code: opts[:verification_code])
    end

    def cancel_verification_code opts
        @nexmo_client.verify.cancel(opts[:request_id])
    end
end
```

in the controller i'm calling the service methods like below

```
class NexmoController < ApplicationController

    def send_verification_code 
        response = NexmoServices.new.send_verification_code params[:nexmo]
        if response.status == '0'
          render json: response.request_id.to_json
        else
          render json: response.error_text.to_json
        end
    end


    def cancel_verification_code 
        response = NexmoServices.new.cancel_verification_code params[:nexmo]
        if response.status == '0'
          render json: response.to_json
        else
          render json: response.error_text.to_json
        end
    end
end
```

I have read that usually there will be call method inside service class and controller will call that. service method call will take care of the rest.

My case im instantiating service objects for all the methods if you see my controller(NexmoService.new).

is it correct??? I want to know the best practise must be followed in this scenario.

Thanks,
Ajith

Comment: I am not sure how many service endpoints you have to map. If it is just a few (as shown) I think the explicit nature of your class is acceptable (and probably better IMHO). However if you have a large number of endpoints to deal with a centralized interface might be easier to manage in the future. Also depending on ruby version keyword arguments might make this easier to read and certainly easier to document. Also adding an `as_json` method to your class could clean up the controller code a bit where by the service can decide which response to render based on its status

Comment: Aside from ruby styleguide compliant (2 space tabs and brackets around method parameters), your code looks perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Regarding the whole "service objects should only contain a `call` method", this is only a rule of thumb; not a strictly enforced design. If you really wanted to abide by that principle here (I wouldn't bother!), you could split this into 3 classes - e.g. `module NexmoServices; class SendVerification < Base`. In this case, I'd be more inclined to put that class in e.g. `app/lib/` rather than `app/services/` though anyway.

Comment: If you intend to split this into classes as mentioned by @TomLord please remember that this needs to live in  `app/lib/nexmo_services/class_name.rb` or `app/services/nexmo_services/class_name.rb` so that rails `Autoload` works correctly with the name spacing

Comment: Thank you all :)